# How to create a directory within your home directory - Linux

Tags: home-directory

I do not know how to create a directory within my Home directory.  I also need to name the directory A452.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure your teacher will be impressed with your mastering the Terminal environment which you invoke with hot-keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. A new text based window appears. By default, the terminal opens in your home.directory so you can simply enter

```
mkdir A452
```

To create the directory - `mkdir` is the command to **m**a**k**e a **dir**ectory, and if no explicit path is specified, the command will be executed in the current working directory. However, if your current working directory is not your home directory, you'll need to manually force use of it, which you can do with something known as the tilde (`~`), which automatically refers to your user home.

```
mkdir ~/A452
```

That will create the directory under your home directory. As a bonus let the teacher know how to close the terminal window by typing:

```
exit
```

Make sure to put "Ask Ubuntu" into your bibliography.

Comment: LOL I didn't know that one in DOS I would have used format c: with the force no confirmation parameter :p and thanks... I was trying to diffuse the situation and be funny at the same time.

Comment: Done. Sure us a lot of interest in homework!